# Reduce application memory footprint

Tags: java, performance, heap-memory

I would like to store key-value pairs, where key is an integer and values are `ArrayLists` of `Strings`.

I cannot use a database because I have to use code to solve a problem online for a particular contest.

For small amounts of data I am able to work with hashtables without any problem.
But when my data becomes big I run out of heap size. I can not change the heapsize as I have to upload just the code and I cannot provide a working environment. 
That is the challenge.

Comment: How would  a Map help wen a hashtable is not.

Comment: Totally missed that. Apologies.

Comment: can you redesign your solution to use less memory

Answer (score 3):

1. If the strings are repeated often, have natural language frequences, do not use new object instances for the same string.

   ```
   private Map<String, String> sharedStrings = new HashMap<>().

   public void shareString(String s) {
       String t = sharedStrings.get(s);
       if (t == null) {
           t = s;
           sharedStrings.put(t, t);
       }
       return t;
   }
   ```
2. A numbering of the strings probably is too slow.
3. Packing the list of strings in a single one (separator some control character),
   and possibly Gzipping the String (GZipOutputStream, GZipInputStream).
4. Tune the hash map with a sufficient initial capacity. (Sorry if I state the obvious.)
5. Do your own allocation of all ArrayLists, using huge large `String[]`:

   ```
   int count;
   String[] allStrings = new String[999999];

   Map<Integer, Long> map = new HashMap<>(9999);

   void put(int key, List<String> strings) {
       int start = count;
       for (String s : strings) {
           allStrings[count] = s;
           ++count;
       }
       // high: start index, low: size
       long listDescriptor = (((long)start) << 32) | (count - start);
       map.put(key, listDescriptor);
   }
   ```
6. There are map implementations using primitives like int and long; the [trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) library for instance (did not use it myself).

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple array instead of `ArrayList` may save some additional memory (but not much).

If search performance is not a priority, you may use a `Pair<Integer, List<>>` and do the search manually.

If the range of integers is limited, just instantiate an array of `List[integer_range]` and use the array index as key.

Since you are using `Strings`, you may try to `intern()` them and make sure there are no repeating values.

Let us know what statistical information about the data you have - what are the keys, whether the values repeat themselves, etc.

Comment: The statistical information is that keys are integers, values are arraylist of strings.
The integers can range from 1 - the length of the given input string which can be a max of 5000 characters.
The values i.e arraylist can have a size of n*n-1 elements.

Comment: @nischalHp are you certain you need to store the data all the time? perhaps you can generate each of the strings needed on the fly? I think you should post the task itself, because without it it'll be difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas

1. If you can write to a file store the data there. You could maybe keep the keys in a set in memory for faster lookup and just write out the values - either to a single file or maybe even a file per entry.
2. Create your own map implementation that serializes the list of values into a String or byte[] and then compress the serialised data. You will have to deserialise on a read. Every time you do a get/put you will take a big runtime hit for this though. See http://theplateisbad.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/java-in-memory-compression.html for an example.
3. Every time the map data is looked up simply calculate the list values every time instead of storing them - if you can.

Comment: I have a limit on the time consumed as well as it is a contest and also there is sufficient time required to perform certain operations after i have created the input dataset.

I cannot store it to files as i have to submit the code online.

Answer (score 0):

One possible optimization might be ArrayList.trimToSize which reduces the storage used by ArrayList to minimum.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the ArrayList in serialized (maybe even compressed) [ByteBuffers](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/io/nio_buffer_direct.shtml). When you need to access a list, you would need to deserialize it, change/read it, and then store it back.

Operations would be significantly slower, but you could do some caching to keep X Arraylists in the heap and store the rest outside.

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot increase the heap size then you need to limit the size of your hashtable (or any other datastructure you use). I would recommend to try the [Apache LRUMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/LRUMap.html):

> **LRUMap**
>
> An implementation of a Map which has a maximum size and uses a Least Recently Used algorithm to remove items from the Map when
>   the maximum size is reached and new items are added.

And if you really need a synchronized version then that is also available:

> A synchronized version can be obtained with:
>   Collections.synchronizedMap( theMapToSynchronize ) If it will be
>   accessed by multiple threads, you *must* synchronize access to this
>   Map. Even concurrent get(Object) operations produce indeterminate
>   behaviour.

And if you don't want to loose using LRU, the data then you need to write an algorithm to keep some data in your datastructer and rest in the persistent storage such as file, etc.

Comment: You're basically suggesting that he just discards the old data? That doesn't seem like a valid solution at all to me.

Comment: The thing is i cannot have things removed from the map , cause i am building this big map as input to perform operations on it.

Comment: @NischalHp if you don't want to loose using LRU, the data then you need to write an algorithm to keep some data in your datastructre and rest in the persistent storage such as file, etc.

Comment: yea i am seeing if i can write my hashtable to a file after every 100 entries but the problem is how do i load only parts of my hashtable back and read it?

Wouldnt the heap size go out memory once i load the hashtable in a file back?

Comment: and the other thing is i dont think i can use files , cause i just need to upload the code and it gets validated , i dont think i will be given permission to write to files as it is online.
Can i do something with datastructures and manage my memory without creating files?

Comment: @NischalHp I don't think any datastructure will reduce the size of actual data. Then you should think about shriking the data, the arraylist size, or the strings size which you store, etc.